# DOMPDF problems with special character like Hebrew language

Tags: utf-8, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am trying to make work with Hebrew language but it is showing ??????? instead of Hebrew content. if anyone suggests. thanks

```
    require  'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

    $html   = empty( $html ) ? $this->get_order_pdf_html( $order_id, 'pdf' ) : $html;

    $dompdf = new Dompdf( array(
        'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
    ) );

    $dompdf->setPaper( 'A4', 'portrait' ); 
    $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
    $dompdf->loadHtml( $html, 'UTF-8' ); 
    $dompdf->render(); 

    $output = $dompdf->output(); 

    if( $save_pdf ) {

        $invoice_file_name = sprintf( '%s/uploads/document-%s-%s.pdf', WP_CONTENT_DIR, $order_id, time("H:s") );
        file_put_contents( $invoice_file_name, $output);
        return $invoice_file_name;
    }

    if( $download_pdf ) {

        $dompdf->stream( sprintf( "%s-%s", __('document'), $order_id ) );
        return true;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: You don't show any of the HTML related to the document. We'd need to see that before we could determine if the problem is with Dompdf or something else. Have you read through the [Unicode How-to](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo)?

Answer (score 0):

font-family: firefly, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
use this font-farmily in your hebrew letter contain element.
good luck